# delayed_job saving entry but not sending out email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job gem to send email upon the destroy of a record.

**comments_controller.rb**

```
def reject_appeal
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.destroy
      @comment.rejection(@comment)
      flash[:alert] = "You have succesfully rejected the appeal."
      redirect_to post(@comment.post_id)
    end
end
```

**comments.rb**

```
   def rejection(comment)
    RejectAppeal.delay.notify(comment)
  end
```

Now if I remove the delay method and just have it as `RejectAppeal.notify(comment)`, the email gets sent out perfectly fine. But with `delay` i don't know what happens. I don't see anything in the delayed job lob log. Although in development log i do notice that the entry gets stored in or at least it `BEGINS` the action.

Any help on this? I am using delay method on several other mailer functions in this same app and they all get sent out fine but i am unsure whats wrong with this

P.S I am using Rails 4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Is the delayed job getting serialized correctly? (Check the delayed_jobs table). Is there an error running the job? The error gets stored in the `last_error` column if so.

It's probably because you are destroying your comment and then passing it through to the delayed job so, when the delayed job runs and tries to load the comment to do something with it, the comment can no longer be found.

Comment: I just realized when I query for the entry the the entire table returns nil, meaning there is no entry for it the in DJ table. Also i tried running it before the destroy still no luck. Plus now I see `Job Delayed::PerformableMailer` in the delayed_job log

Comment: To check if it is serializing correctly you'd be better off turning your delayed jobs processor off. You might also need to configure delayed jobs to keep failed jobs around with `Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false`

Comment: ahan ! just found out. It says `Delayed::DeserializationError`

Comment: same error as here - https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/587#issuecomment-29073203